# How do I align text to the input using grids

Tags: html, css, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

I need the text and the input to be vertically aligned.

This is my code:

```
 <span> contenidoEmail</span>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9">
                    <p>Para: </p>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_7-of-9">
                    <div class="slds-form-element">
                          <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1"></label>
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                            <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1" class="slds-input" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9"></div>
            </div>
```

This is what it looks like:[image]

Comment: add your css grids code

Comment: i don't have any css code, it's all about sf frame @Riskbreaker

Comment: ok since you are using a third party like : slds-grid - Its best for you to go to their support...